# Controlling a linked list queue from my user/main class, not working

Tags: java, for-loop, data-structures, linked-list, queue

Okay so I need to create `queue`(contains enqueue, dequeue, and isEmpty methods), `queueNode`(stores names, setters and getters), and `queueUser`(Main) classes. User enters one name at a time. Once 3 names have been entered, each new name entered will kick the front of the queue to the screen. This process will continue until the user enters "quit" as the name. Once this happens, all the remaining names will be displayed. I have everything but my user/main class. I can't seem to get it to work properly. It accepts 3 names, and after the third name is entered, displays the first name that was entered. Problem is, it stops there. I need it to keep going. I have a feeling I need a different loop, but I am just stuck right now. No help from my instructor, nothing in my textbook, and I have hit a brick wall. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. I am still fairly new to Java and totally new to data structures.

***queueUser***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class queueUser {

public static void main(String[] args){
    queue qName = new queue();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int limit = 3;
    String name;
    String stop = "quit";
    boolean flag = false;

do{

    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter one name: ");      
        name = input.nextLine();
            if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(stop)){
                qName.enqueue(name);
                flag = true;
            }else{
                flag = false;
                while(!qName.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(qName.dequeue());
                    }
                }
            }
        System.out.println(qName.dequeue());

    }while(!flag);
  }
}
```

***queue***

```
public class queue{

queueNode front, rear;
int count = 0;

public queue(){
    front = null;
    rear = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    boolean empty = false;
        if(front == null){
            empty = true;
        }else{
            empty = false;
        }
    return empty;
}

public void enqueue(String pName){
    queueNode node = new queueNode(pName);
        if(isEmpty()){
            front = node;
        }else{
            rear.setNext(node);
        }
    rear = node;
}

public String dequeue(){
    String firstName = null;
    if(isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Queue is empty!");
    }else{
        firstName = front.getName();
        front = front.getNext();
    }
    return firstName;
  } 
}
```

***queueNode***

```
public class queueNode {

private String name;
private queueNode next;

public queueNode(String pName){
    name = pName;
}

public void setNext(queueNode pNext){
    next = pNext;
}

public queueNode getNext(){
    return next;
}

public void setName(String pName){
    name = pName;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: your professor)

In your loop code you are saying this:

Give me three names, but I'll stop if any the most recent name given was "quit".
After you give me these three names, I will tell you whats on top of the queue.
Now do it all over again.

You are not removing from the queue when you repeat the loop until you have put in an additional 3 names. Even then, you will only dequeue the top, leaving 4 in the queue.

First and foremost, you have a variable int count in your queue class that is never used. If you use that, it will GREATLY improve the solution here. When something is enqueued, increment the count variable. Decrement when dequeued. Add a method that will return the count variable. Then just do this:

```
boolean flag = false;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter one name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) flag = true;
    if (!flag) qName.enqueue(name);
    if (qName.getCount() > 3) System.out.println(qName.dequeue());
} while (!flag);
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) System.out.println(qName.dequeue());
```

If your instructor wants it otherwise, then your code should be as follows:

```
boolean flag = false;
int count = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter one name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) flag = true;
    if (!flag) {
        count++;
        qName.enqueue(name);
    }
    if (count > 3) {
        count--;
        System.out.println(qName.dequeue());
    }
} while (!flag);
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) System.out.println(qName.dequeue());
```

Comment: Thank you! But, I actually meant to take that count out of my queue class. I was originally gonna keep track of how many names were in the queue in there, but then I was told that count is to be done in the queueUser. All other classes, as my instructor described "will be dumb" and don't count anything.

Comment: Yes. You could put it where your instructor says to do so, but it is far easier to put it in the queue class for the reasons I have given. Just a few additional lines of code in the Queue class gives you the ability to check the size of the queue w/o having to inc/dec in your main class which makes nested loops in nested loops.

Comment: Yeah he is not exactly a fan of "easier" lol, I'll give it a try and get back.

Comment: My edit should fit his desire to have a counter in your main class.

Comment: One additional check you can put into your code is to modify that for loop to say for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) System.out.println(qName.dequeue()); This way if the code is told to stop even before 3 names are put into the queue it will still exit correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** All of these apply to your QueueUser class.

1. Make sure you CamelCase your class names.
2. The do-while loop is redundant since the flag starting value is false. You can accomplish the same thing by just making it a while loop (unless that was a requirement by your professor to have one).

   ```
   while(!flag) {
       //do your stuff
   }
   ```
3. Completely get rid of the for loop.
4. The problem with your original code is that the flag values are switched around, the flag is already false so there is no need to declare that in the do-while loop. If you wanted to leave this redundant portion in it would need to be flag = false.

   ```
   if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(stop)){
           qName.enqueue(name);
           flag = true; //<-----SHOULD BE FALSE if you don't want to break the loop (is redundant)
       }else {
           flag = false //<-------CHANGE TO TRUE
   ```
5. Set the limit variable to 0 (or rename it count and set it to 0) to satisfy the count functionality your professor wants and add an if statement in your while loop to dequeue when it reaches 3.

   ```
   count++
   if(count >= 3) {
       System.out.println(qName.dequeue());
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Yes, this is close. Sorry, the directions I got were a bit hazy as well and couldn't figure how to explain it better. So I just posted from the directions I was given. Basically, after 3 names are entered, it'll display the first name entered. Then after that every time a new name is entered, it will dequeue and display the next name in the queue.

Comment: I edited my response, you should only need little modifications to your code. This should satisfy all your requirements.